# The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of gunicorn.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units

Tags: linux, deployment, gunicorn, daemon, systemctl

I'm trying to deploy and this is where I'm at.. I'm a little lost into why its reacting this way?

```
sats@test-server:~/portfolio$ ls
```

db.sqlite3  manage.py  portfolio  Portfolio_images  portfolio.sock  projects  requirements.txt  static
sats@test-server:~/portfolio$ sudo systemctl start gunicorn

[sudo] password for sats:
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of gunicorn.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
sats@test-server:~/portfolio$ systemctl daemon-reload
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon ===
Authentication is required to reload the systemd state.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:

1. ubuntu
2. ,,, (sats)
   Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2): Failed to reload daemon: Method call timed out
   sats@test-server:~/portfolio$